# how to drag and zoom big movieclips on flash? (like googlemaps - withouth the +- buttons)

Tags: flash, zooming, drag

that's about it. I want a big movieclip or image to be dragable around the screen like a map. 
i'm very new to actionscript so please be descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Your easiest option would be to use the [ScrollPane](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/containers/ScrollPane.html) control in Flash.

You could get away with no code at all initially.

1. Drag a ScrollPane component from the
   Components Panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> on Windows/Linux /<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> on OSX)
2. Set scrollDrag to true in the
   Parameters tab
3. Input the path to a movie clip's
   linkage id in the ScollPane's source
   parameter.

Have a look at the documetation and examples.

**Option 2**: Use a mask:

1. set a mask in the IDE or using actionscript to your `bigMovieClip`
2. add event listeners for `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_UP` to setup dragging

actioncript 3 required:

```
bigMovieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragOn);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragOff);

function dragOn(event:MouseEvent):void{
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
function dragOff(event:MouseEvent):void{
    bigMovieClip.stopDrag();
}
```

**Option 3:** Use the [scrollRect](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect) property of MovieClip

If your clip is 1000x1000 for example, and you want your visible area to be 500x500 starting from 0,0 all you need to do is

```
bigMovieClip.scrollRect = new Rectangle(0,0,500,500);
```

then when you need to scroll,
you store the rectangle, modify the `x` or `y` depending on your needs and update the scrollRect

```
var sRect:Rectangle = bigMovieClip.scrollRect;
sRect.x += 20;
bigMovieClip.scrollRect = sRect;
```

Good luck

Comment: ok. first, thank you for the answer.
second, i tried the scrollpanel example, and it's more or less what i'm searching for, except i don't want to have horizontal and vertical bars, and i would like the little map to be on the left. is that possible?
the second and third examples i don't understand, if you could be even more specific, like you're talking to a 7 year old, it would be great :)
(i don'tknow what IDE is, and how to do a mask)

Comment: ok so i did the mask thing!! but now it is saying something like this:

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property stopDrag not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/dragOff()

so it just keeps glued to the mouse and i can't drag anymore. Is it not compatible with as3, or it's something else?

Comment: hey i'm sorry to be commenting so much, but i think i got it, i just changed "stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragOff);" to "bigmovieclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragOff);" and i think it is working. thank you!

Comment: Hi, IDE means Flash, the editing tool itself, so what I meant was manually drawing the mask on a layer above your big clip and setting the layer mode to Mask. I've fixed the error thingy, the mouse up should be set on stage because you can press on the big clip, but release outside and dragging might not stop.